# how can I use google oauth in expo go app?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, google-oauth, expo-go

I'm trying to implement google auth provider in my expo app (android for now), at the moment I'm developing it using Expo Go for convenience. The problem is I have to provide the apps SHA-1 certificate to google in order for it to work.
The question is, can I use Expo Go with google auth somehow? or do I need to create a standalone build and create the key to sign it?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it is impossible with Expo Go to use Google authentication https://docs.expo.dev/guides/google-authentication/